# Selecting on names has inconsistent behavior

Tags: postgresql

I have a database in PostgreSQL with the local authorities and regions in the UK. I trimmed the names when loading into Postgres. If I search in one table, I get a match only with the exact string, but if I search in another table I get a match with the exact string and also with trailing whitespaces. It is the same match, as you can see by the same `regionid` primary key and by the last query with `LIKE`. Here is the output in `psql`:

```
db=> select * from la where name = 'Rutland';
   lau1    |  name   | regionid 
-----------+---------+----------
 E06000017 | Rutland |        4
(1 row)

db=> select * from la where name = 'Rutland ';
 lau1 | name | regionid 
------+------+----------
(0 rows)

db=> select * from region where name = 'West Midlands';
 regionid |           name           
----------+--------------------------
        5 | West Midlands           
(1 row)

db=> select * from region where name = 'West Midlands   ';
 regionid |           name           
----------+--------------------------
        5 | West Midlands           
(1 row)

db=> select * from region where name like 'West Midland%';
 regionid |           name           
----------+--------------------------
        5 | West Midlands           
(1 row)
```

I am running Postgres on Azure with this version:

```
db=> SELECT version();
                          version                           
------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

*Update*: The schemas are:

```
db=> \d la
                         Table "public.la"
  Column  |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 lau1     | character(9)          |           | not null | 
 name     | character varying(50) |           | not null | 
 regionid | integer               |           | not null | 

dbr=> \d region
                   Table "public.region"
  Column  |     Type      | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+---------------+-----------+----------+---------
 regionid | smallint      |           | not null | 
 name     | character(24) |           | not null |
```

What is going on?

Comment: Could you add the schema for both tables?

Comment: Yes, I did that. One has `character` and the other has `character varying`. So the first one is automatically padded.

Comment: Yeah, that was my guess. That is why they behave differently.

Comment: Well done. I found [this manual reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html): "Values of type character are physically padded with spaces to the specified width n, and are stored and displayed that way. However, trailing spaces are treated as semantically insignificant and disregarded when comparing two values of type character." Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: In a nutshell: do not use `char` or `character` data type. They are just there for historical reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between those tables is that`la.name` is `varchar(50)`, while `region.name` is `char(24)`. `char` differs from `varchar` in that the trailing spaces are ignored. To quote the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html):

> Values of type character are physically padded with spaces to the specified width n, and are stored and displayed that way. However, trailing spaces are treated as semantically insignificant and disregarded when comparing two values of type character.